# Xbox Live not available on boot, but is after sign out?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

My brother has an Xbox One and when he turns it on, he does not get automatically signed into Xbox Live. On top of that, when he tries to sign in manually, he can't, and so most online functionality is limited, though he can still download updates and patches for games.

However, if he signs out of his local account, and then signs back in, he is signed into Xbox Live automatically and everything works perfect.

Essentially it only happens on boot, so does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Is he using Kinect? Because automatic sign-in only works when using Kinect. Unless this has been patched?